# Lie groups exponential map intuition.

Tags: lie-groups, intuition, rotations

I am having a hard time wrapping the exponential map around my head. So if $G$ is a Lie group we have this map :
$exp : T_eG \rightarrow G $
My understanding of lie groups is that they represent stuff like rotations. So if I take $G=O(n)$ the rotations, then I know that $T_{I_n}O(n) = \text{skew symmetric matrices}$.
So I take one skew symmetric matrix $S$ which as I understand it somehow represents an infinitesimal rotation. Then $exp(tS)$ is a curve for which the elements are rotations of $O(n)$. But what do these element mean? How to think intuitively about what this exponential map actually is?

**Edit :**

Sorry, but I don't see how the linked answers tell me how to think about the curve $\gamma(t)=exp(tX)$, and neither did OP since apparently they were not accepted...

Comment: The elements (say for the 2x2 case) would be something like $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta(t)&\sin\theta(t)\\-\sin\theta(t)&\cos\theta(t)\end{pmatrix}$$The different choices of $S$ give different paths $\theta(t)$.

Comment: @JohnDoe wouldn't the different choice of S change the axe of rotation in 3D?

Comment: Yes sure in higher dimensions

Comment: Meanwhile there are some nice videos (eg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHOcoIyJj2o) on youtube by Joan Sola, explaining the intuition behind Lie theroy. Seach for "Lie theory for the roboticist"